# Conditional Expectation of Poisson Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

I have a Poisson Process with stationary and independent increments.  Therefore I know:
$$P(N_T - N_t = r) = \dfrac{\exp(-\lambda(T-t))(\lambda(T-t))^r}{r!} \mbox{ where } T>t.$$

Now suppose I am considering a process where:
$Y_t = \exp(N_t - ct)$

How do I calculate the conditional expectation of $E(Y_T|Y_t)$?  And under what conditions would I have a Martingale process?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Sorry, I am new here and am unfamiliar with the process. Based on the Q&A I thought I was just supposed to stick with the question and avoid discussing what I'd tried.  I'll provide a bit more explanation.

What I was given was the assumption of independent and stationary increments, so I used the general definition of a Poisson process to arrive at the probability equation above.  Then I wrote out what I know about conditional expectation. Namely:
$E[Y_T|Y_t] = \sum_{j=1}^{n}y_jP(Y_T=y_j|Y_t)$
Then I took the fact that $P(Y_T=k|Y_t=n)=\frac{P(Y_T=k,Y_t=n)}{P(Y_t = n)}$

And then I tried to plug in the original equation of a Poisson process:
$P(N_t = k) = \dfrac{(\lambda*t)^k}{r!}*\exp(-\lambda(t))$

I decided that because of the independence assumption my 
$E[Y_T|Y_t]$ was simply equal to $E[Y_{_{T-t}}]$

But I am struggling to see how to use this in my new process since the $N_t$ is embedded in the process: 
$Y_t = \exp(N_t - ct)$.

Comment: Hint use independent increment. $Y_T-Y_t$ is independent of $Y_t$. A minor note: to prove a martingale $E(Y_T|\mathcal{F}_t)=Y_t$ where F is the filtration. This is only equal to $E(Y_T|Y_t)$ because $Y$ is a Markov process.

Comment: Note martingales have constant expectation and $EY_0 = 1$, so it must be the case that $E \exp(N_t) = \exp(ct)$. Then you need to show for this value of c, it is actually a martingale.

Comment: as a general note: please make some attempt at the questions and write that what you have tried. as it stands, this question does not meet the quality expectation of this site. For this, please consult the Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, note that, if $X_a$ is Poisson with parameter $a$,
$$
E[\mathrm e^{X_a}]=\sum_n\mathrm e^{-a}\frac{a^n}{n!}\mathrm e^n=\mathrm e^{a(\mathrm e-1)}.
$$
Then, decompose $Y_T$ as $Y_T=\mathrm e^{N_t-cT}\mathrm e^{N_T-N_t}=Y_t\mathrm e^{-c(T-t)}\mathrm e^{N_T-N_t}$ and note that $N_T-N_t$ is Poisson with parameter $a=\lambda(T-t)$ and independent of $Y_t$. Hence
$$
E[Y_T\mid Y_t]=Y_t\mathrm e^{-c(T-t)}E[\mathrm e^{N_T-N_t}]=Y_t\mathrm e^{-c(T-t)}\mathrm e^{\lambda(T-t)(\mathrm e-1)},
$$
and $E[Y_T\mid Y_t]=Y_t$ if $c=$ $____$.

Comment: Thank you so much, Did!  I did not think to decompose $Y_T$ in that way - that is a huge help.  Now I see that if I set $-c(T-t)+\lambda(T-t)(e-1)$ equal to zero and solve for $c$  I should know what condition is required for the Martingale.

Comment: Hmm.. not sure about your decomposition. How you arrived to $-c(T-t)$ leads me to think you had a typo or something.

Comment: @daOnlyBG Thanks for your comment. Think harder.